# Literature on nonparametric density estimation

Tags: estimation, references, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I am about to write my bachelor thesis about non-parametric density estimation, especially kernel density estimators and their application in classification. As I am quite new to looking for academic literature, I am having a hard time finding the most important and modern papers, or other resources, and would be glad if someone could give me a hint. Right now I am mainly working with older works (especially by Silverman and Devroye).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kernel Smoothing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412552701) by Wand & Jones was my main book reference, you can follow the literature from their bibliography. It's very well written, thin and technical just enough

Comment: This would also be my first choice; I've read a number of books before (Silverman, for one example) and since (books by Härdle for example), but we used a pre-published draft of this book in a course Matt taught and even though it was still not quite in its final form it was quite a good book.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Aksakal, there are two more classical books that are worth recommending:

> Silverman, B. W. (1986). Density estimation for statistics and data
>   analysis. CRC press.
>
> Scott, D. W. (2015). Multivariate density estimation: theory,
>   practice, and visualization. John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Silverman has many important papers in the field

Answer (score 0):

Density estimation is obviously a vastly studied topic. If you care for results in density estimation with provable guarantees on sample complexity and time of computation, while having approximation up to arbitrarily low error, I strongly recommend you peruse literature from the Theoretical Computer Science community.

A starting point could be [this](http://www.iliasdiakonikolas.org/stoc14-workshop/diakonikolas.pdf) presentation by Diakonikolas, and then, consequently [this](http://www.crcnetbase.com/doi/abs/10.1201/b19567-21) survey again by Diakonikolas. You will find folklore and more recent results on non-parametric density estimation, for discrete and continuous distributions. The references in the presentation and survey all contain pointers to a wealth of literature (with clear discussion on applications) on density estimation, studied by various communities.

I also recommend the books by [Devroye-Lugosi](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-0125-7) and [Devroye-Gvorfi](https://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/nonpar_dens_en.html), as well as the terse book by [Tsybakov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb13794), again, if you want theoretically flavoured discussions about density estimation.

Comment: Another (wild) idea could be to see saddlepoint approximation from an empirical cumulant generating function as density estimation. Do not know if anythjing is written!  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781  for a starting point. Could be very interesting!